# Is there a generic Type in Dart like Class<T> in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: dart, generics

In Kotlin I can do something like:

```kotlin
var myType : KClass<String>? = null
```

and can assign to it like:

```kotlin
myType = String::class
```

but NOT like:

```kotlin
myType = Int::class // Type mismatch: inferred type in KClass<Int> but KClass<String>? was expected
```

Is there something similar in Dart? I know of the `Type` type but it is not generic and while it can represent `String` or `List<int>` I seem not to be able to write similar code as my Kotlin example:

```dart
Type? t = null;
```

I can assign to it:

```dart
t = String;
```

AND also:

```dart
t = int;
```

but I want the second example to fail compilation. I would need some kind of `Type<String>`. Is this possible in Dart?

Comment: Why can't you do `'' is String` or `1 is String`?  Why do you need something generic?  Or if you really need a generic function, why not `bool test<T>(Object? object) => object is T;`?  Or if you need a compile-time error, then `void test<T>(T object) {}` also seems like it'd do, but that seems pretty silly.  Just declare the type you want in the first place.

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't need to test the type, I think the name of the method is confusing, I will change the name. In general, this is a very simplistic sample I can show what I want with, not the real code - I just want to know if there is something like Type<T>.

Comment: I don't know what `Type<T>` is supposed to *do* or mean.  For your `aFunction` example, you should make it generic in the first place: `aFunction<T>(T argument)`, and you could call it as `aFunction<String>('')` (or omit the type and let it be inferred).  If you need to pass a `Type` object as an actual argument, then no, there is nothing you can do at compile-time.  But really you should avoid using `Type` objects; they aren't very useful.  This sounds like a probable [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); it would help to see what you actually want to do.

Comment: I do need the type. Maybe my example is not the best, let me edit again. But I suppose there is nothing like it anyway.

Comment: My code is already working, it's just that I don't like some of the lax type safety I have in there that I wouldn't have in Kotlin, and I'm trying to learn whether I can make it better.

Comment: Please just show the code that you want to make more type-safe. That is what you are ultimately trying to do, so that is what you should be asking about, not some specific way you think could solve your problem.

Comment: I am curious about whether this is possible to do in Dart, independent of my code. It's fine if it isn't, just please give me the answer to this question, or don't, your call. I don't want to ask about my original problem because to be honest it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Type` class is not generic, and doesn't support subtype checks (or any other reasonable type-related operation). There is no way to use it for what you are trying to do.

So, don't. It's useless anyway. However, in Dart you can create your *own* type representation that is actually useful, because Dart doesn't erase type arguments, and you can then ask people using your code to ass that instead.

Say:

```dart
class MyType<T> implements Comparable<MyType>{ // Or a better name.
  const MyType();
  Type get type => T;
  bool operator >=(MyType other) => other is MyType<T>;
  bool operator <=(MyType other) => other >= this;
  bool isInstance(Object? object) => object is T;
  R runWith<R>(R Function<T>() action) => action<T>();
  @override
  int get hashCode => T.hashCode;
  @override
  bool operator==(Object other) => other is MyType && T == other.type;
}
```

With that you can write:

```dart
MyType<String?> type;
type = MyType<Null>(); // valid
type = MyType<String>(); // valid
type = MyType<Never>(); // valid
type = MyType<int>; // EEEK! compile-time error
```

You can use it where you need to store a type as a value.

The thing is, most of the time you can just use a type variable instead ,and creating an actual value to represent a type is overkill.
So, *first* try to just use a type parameter, instead of passing around `Type` or `MyType` objects. Only if that fails should you consider using `MyType`. Using `Type` is probably a mistake since it's not good for anything except doing `==` checks, which is antithetical to object orientation's idea of subtype subsumption.

Comment: I actually have a map Type -> some object, I think this is a reasonable use case? This is also something what Flutter does, Element keeps a map Type -> InheritedElement. The objects that are values in the map are generic with T and there is a 'register' function - I wanted to make sure that it is called with a Type and an object that are compatible in T.

Comment: Can't do that, you cannot check anything about a `Type` object other than whether it's `==` another `Type` object. That's why I always recommend using something else (and I'd recommend this to Flutter too.) Heck, I'd make a `TypeMap` with `get<T>` and `set<T>` methods to allow you to do lookups on real types, not `Type` objects before I'd consider using a `Type` object for anything.

Comment: Yes, I understood your point. I will try to take a look at other solutions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best you can get :

```
void main() {
  aFunction<String>(String, '');
  aFunction<String>(String, 1);
}

void aFunction<V>(Type type, V value) {
  print(value.toString());
}
```

if you run this in a dartpad, you will see that

```
aFunction<String>(type, 1);
```

Doesn't compile.

But that's not really efficient because the type isn't guessed by Dart, you have to specify the generic type by hand.

> I'm using Dart 2.17

Comment: Yeah but in this case there is no need for me to pass the Type parameter as it is completely unused in the body. I want to be able to only pass Type values that are compatible with the type parameter V. I edited the question to present what I have in mind in a much simpler way (I hope).

Comment: That's all you can achieve in Dart. You can't apply your kotlin logic to solve your problem. You have to think with Dart in mind. Type represent a runtime type, so you can't make static assertion on it